# "Update Service Reference" populates project namespace in 'Reference.cs'

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2019

In the WCF application, I have two different solutions for client and service. Service reference was already added. But after modifying Service contracts and methods, I tried to `Update Service Reference` (Service was running without Debug mode).

Service reference gets updated but the namespace name is populated for all the methods in the **Reference.cs** file as `NamsSpaceName.ReferenceName.ServiceMethod`, whereas it is supposed to be `ReferenceName.ServiceMethod`.

How can I fix this issue? I do not need the NamespaceName to be populated before RefrenceName.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no other option working. So, I had to manually edit the **Reference.cs**. Usually it is not recommended to manually edit the **Reference.cs** file as it is `Auto-Generated`. I had to carefully edit the populated **Namespace** and finally it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following method：select Service References directory, open Properties window and check if its Namespace Provider property is set to false.

Comment: Hello @jiayao, thank you for your response, i tried your suggestion but it did not work for me as well.

Comment: I have also tried unchecking ```reuse types in referenced assemblies``` in **Configure Service Reference** and that did not work as well.